# Group DataFrame conditionally in Python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to group my DataFrame conditionally based on the value in a particular column.

Here is an example of my dataframe I am working with:

```
  date       id     height 
dd/mm/yyyy   1A     6
dd/mm/yyyy   2A     4
dd/mm/yyyy   1B     5
dd/mm/yyyy   2B     1
```

I want to be able to group all of my observations based on whether or not they have "A" or "B" in their `id` column values. I have tried using the .filter() method like so:

`sides = df.groupby("id").filter(lambda group: "A" in group["id])`

But nothing happens I just get a blank dataframe with my columns "date", "id", and "height" but nothing else.  I'm new to python and pandas and would like to know if I can separate these groups the way I described above.

Comment: `df.groupby(df.id.str[-1])`? Perhaps also susbet first to `df[df.id.str[-1].isin(['A', 'B'])]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will do the trick

```
sides= df[df['id'].str.contains("A")]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `groupby` with a function (or a lambda). Here you could use:

```
grp = df.groupby(lambda x: 'A' in df.loc[x, 'id'])
```

For example you get sum the heights for row containing or not `'A'` with:

```
df.groupby(lambda x: 'A' in df.loc[x, 'id']).sum()
```

which gives:

```
       height
False       6
True       10
```

Comment: Thanks this is another interesting solution. I like that the True and False are contained in the same DatFrame.